# RoR: Check for a location within a radius of the other location, using google maps api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, geocoding, gmaps4rails

I am using google maps fo rails gem https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/ . I am trying to find out a way through which I can see if a location is inside the map circle. For instance

```
@circles_json = '[
 {"lng": -122.214897, "lat": 37.772323, "radius": 1000000},
]
```

'

This helps me create the circle. But how do I see if, lets say, 'Location B' is inside `@circles_json` ?

I was thinking of using the gem `ruby geocoder`http://www.rubygeocoder.com/. If so, how do I go ahead with that? I watched the railscasts. But it mostly depends on the local db. What I am looking for is to see if the two location entered in my database fall close to each other or not. In this case, in a 50M radius.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check if a point is within a circle, calculate the distance between the point and the circle's center. If the distance is greater than the radius, it is outside the circle. If the radius is greater than the distance, it is inside the circle.

Ruby Geocoder has a convenient method to calculate the distance between two points.

```
Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(point1, point2)
```

To make this return true/false, use a simple comparator:

```
in_circle? = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(point1, point2) < radius
```

Read the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Calculations%3adistance_between) for help using `#distance_between`.

Comment: Yes,I see in the terminal that as you said, some complex geodesic functions are carried out. That being said, I have this in my model `@locations = Product.near(Geocoder.coordinates(@product.first_address), 50, :order => :distance)` . But the thing is, I want to see if `@product.second_address` lies inside `@locations`

Comment: Also, when you say `It returns a collection of Thing objects that fall within :radius miles`, I understand thats how Geocoder works. Although, i dont have any db columns that needs to return. Just a comparison to return `true or false`. Hope i am making sense :)

Comment: any further guidance or help is highly appreciated. Thanks, @gg_s :)

Comment: I see, you want to check arbitrary coordinates. Ok, let me think about it. I will edit my answer if I come up with something, otherwise I will delete it.

Comment: thanks for taking the time. even I am working on it. If I come up with something will let u know as well. thanks